# c++ std::stream double values no scientific and no fixed count of decimals

Tags: c++, stl

The following code will print value of a and b:

```
double a = 3.0, b=1231231231233.0123456;
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
cout.unsetf(std::ios::scientific);
cout << a << endl << b << endl
```

The output is:

```
3.000000
1231231231233.012451
```

You can see that a is outputed with fixed 6 count of decimals.
But I want the output like this:

```
3
1231231231233.012451
```

How can i set flags only once, and output the above result.

Comment: it seems that there is no direct way to do this...sigh...

Answer (score 0):

The stream inserts `0`s following the double because the stream's default precision for the output of floating-point values is 6. Unfortunately there is no straightforward way of checking if the double represents a whole number (so you could then only print the integral part). What you *could* do however is cast the value to an integer.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(a);
```

Comment: Can't you just check via `x == floor(x)`?

Comment: @StilesCrisis I said there was no *straightforward* way. Should we check the variable each time we want to output it? Or should we do the entire operation inside of a custom `std::num_put` facet?

Comment: double c = 3.13; cout << c << endl;  i need it output 3.13 instead of 3.130000

Comment: @fatmck Change the precision to 2: `std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << c`. But that also requires you to change the precision back to 6 if you want to see more decimal places in your variable `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The default formatting for floating point numbers won't support the formats as requested. There are basically three settings you could use:

- `std::fixed` which will use `precision()` digits after the decimal point.
- `std::scientific` which will use scientific notation with `precision()` digits.
- `std::defaultfloat` which will choose the shorter of the two forms.

(there is also `std::hexfloat` but that just formats the number in an form which is conveniently machine readable).

What you *could* do is to create you own `std::num_put<char>` facet which formats the value into a local buffer using `std::fixed` formatting an strips off trailing zero digits before sending the values one.