# How to swich back from scientific notation

Tags: c++, scientific-notation

I need to show one element in scientific notation. The cout is located inside few loops and after setting the scientific notation, it affects the whole cout in the program.
How can I switch back to regular notation.

This is the cout line:

```
cout << "Firing '" <<  fir << "' Time: " << time <<  " sec\nCorresponding altitude: " << scientific << alt << endl;
```

Only the variable alt should be shown in scientific notation.

I added cout.precision(2); and cout << fixed; after the line above but it also affects the other cout in the program.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can't you define cout.precision(2) before the **cout line** and then output a part of the line, then change the precision cout.precision(10) and output the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/

```
cout << "Firing '" <<  fir << "' Time: " << time <<  " sec\nCorresponding altitude: ";
cout << std::scientific << alt << endl;
std::cout << std::defaultfloat; // C++ 11
```

... or ...

```
std::cout.unsetf ( std::ios::floatfield );   // C++ 98
```

See also:

[c++ std::stream double values no scientific and no fixed count of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985769/c-stdstream-double-values-no-scientific-and-no-fixed-count-of-decimals)

http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps149s/fall99/resources/n2.html

http://www.uow.edu.au/~lukes/TEXTBOOK/notes-cpp/io/omanipulators.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you set the precision, you can store it with `cout.precision()`, in a variable. After you are done using the precision set to 2, reset back to where it was using the variable. i.e. `cout.precision(precision)` assuming "precision" is your variable.

example:

output:

1.2

1.234

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int precision;
float number = 1.234;

int  main(void)
{
  precision = cout.precision();
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << number << endl;
  cout.precision(precision);
  cout << number << endl;
}
```